# Android app hangs on restart (Appcelerator Titanium)

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am making an app for Android. I encountered strange issue.
Application works perfectly until it is closed with back button. If so, than after restart it is showing splash screen and becoming non-responsive. After some time dialog (if I want to close the app) may show.
It happens with any code. For example:

```
var myApp = {};
alert(1);
alert(2);
```

If app is closed in hard way (third button and swiping app out) than everything is fine.

Problem occurs on every Android version both on device and simulator. After some test I found it occurs on SDK 5.2.0 and newer.

Did anyone encounter such problem?

Comment: please add some information about your setup: Titanum SDK version, Android version, does it happen on a device or simulator

Comment: @miga: Sorry my mistake - I did not add such details because it was common problem on every configuration I'd tested. I wast testing it today and found that problem doesn't occur on 5.1.1GA and 5.1.2GA. It occurs on everything newer 5.2.0-5.5.1GA. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I thought it was something with my LiveView but I'm encountering the same issue. SDK5.4.0.

Comment: @GerbenHofman: I have such situation no matter if I use LiveView or not.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as I described in another answer
[Appcelerator app doesn't restart (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807028/appcelerator-app-doesnt-restart-android/40978001#40978001)

Add this property in tiapp.xml:

```
<property name="ti.android.root.reappears.restart" type="bool">true</property>
```

in the root of the `<ti:app>` tag