# Appcelerator app doesn't restart (Android)

Tags: android, appcelerator

I've created an app, everything works fine.

However, when I close the app bij pressing back, and open the app again, it doesn't pass the splash-screen.

If I completely close the app through the Android running apps screen, it opens like normal again.

Anyone had this problem before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you please add some more information: ti sdk version, perhaps some source code. And does a new/plain app work correctly? You could also try to set 'exitOnClose:true' on your window.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, ti-5.4.0 on ALL Android devices.

Comment: Ti sdk 5.5 here, I Will try to update, maybe that will work.

Comment: check if your app launch in singleTask Mode

     android:launchMode="singleTask"

Comment: Hi you can try by @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  int id= android.os.Process.myPid();
     android.os.Process.killProcess(id);
 }

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding this property in tiapp.xml in the root of the `<ti:app>` tag:

```
<property name="ti.android.root.reappears.restart" type="bool">true</property>
```

and remove:

```
<property name="run-on-main-thread" type="bool">true</property>
```

Comment: try to remove `<property name="run-on-main-thread" type="bool">true</property>`

Answer (score 0):

Update your app to Ti SDK 6.0.0. This will fix the issue, I tested it by myself. Also see: [app will freeze if re-launch from the task bar after closing it using Titanium.Android.currentActivity.finish();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40990418/app-will-freeze-if-re-launch-from-the-task-bar-after-closing-it-using-titanium-a?noredirect=1&lq=1)