# app will freeze if re-launch from the task bar after closing it using Titanium.Android.currentActivity.finish();

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

anyone knows any workaround?
We are closing the application by calling this line of code Titanium.Android.currentActivity.finish() when the user tap the back button(device back). Though the application will close completely, if the user tried to re-launch the app using the recent apps(task bar), the application will freeze that affects device performance.

I created a new app, tested it and was able to replicate the issue.

Anyone knows a work-around?

Steps:
1. Create an app
2. Create a window in index.xml
3. add event listener and open the window on your index.js

```
$.container.addEventListener('androidback', function(){
    Titanium.Android.currentActivity.finish();
});

$.container.open();
```

OS Info:
[image]

Comment: post some code for better understanding

Comment: i added the code implementation.

Comment: May be: `<property name="ti.android.bug2373.finishfalseroot" type="bool">true</property>`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as I described in another answer
[Appcelerator app doesn't restart (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807028/appcelerator-app-doesnt-restart-android/40978001#40978001)

Add the following property in tiapp.xml

```
<property name="ti.android.root.reappears.restart" type="bool">true</property>
```

in the root of the `<ti:app>` tag

Comment: try to remove `<property name="run-on-main-thread" type="bool">true</property>`

Comment: Nope. That will not work. It has something to do with hyperloop. By the way, the issue was already resolved by upgrading SDK to 6.0.0(latest)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved using SDK 6.0.0.
Just need to re-compile existing modules to make it compatible with the said SDK version.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: unfortunately none. :( i am now looking in the internet to check if there are available source codes. i need to re-compile at least 6 modules.. hahahaha

Comment: I created a sample application using 5.5.1 sdk, then the issue occurred, thats the reason I said it is an appcelerator's issue. But when I updated the sdk to 6.0.0 and re-build the application, the issue no longer occur. :)

Comment: I also tested this and I can also verify that this issue is fixed on SDK 6.0.0