# How can I restart an appcelerator android app?

Tags: android, appcelerator, restart

Hi I'm developing an android app in appcelerator titanium. When ca user makes a certain action I need to restart the app. How can I do this? I read that I ca do this by using android activity and intents. Can someone show me how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

try this to restart your application

```
 Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
             .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I also found this piece of code but my app is developed in Appcelerator Titanium. I know I can use hyperloop to write some Java code, but I thought there is a javascript solution.
Thank you! :)

Comment: @CristiCalacianu https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452206/android-app-hangs-on-restart-appcelerator-titanium

Comment: I placed that in my tiapp.xml and it help in avoiding the app to become unresponsive when reopen. My question is how can I restart the app doing something like this: button.addEventlistener('click', function(){
// restart the app on click event
});

Answer (score 0):

By restarting do you mean like reload alloy.js and then index.js, the same when it happens as if the application was closed and re-launched fresh? If alloy.js is not be re-executed again, you can try to keep track of all the opened windows in an array, then on the button click, close all the windows and relaunch index.js or the controller whichever is your entry point to the application.

**Sample code to store window references**

```
windowStack.push({
   windowObj : windowObject, //Ti.UI.createWindow
   winName : windowName,     //Provide a human readable name for logs
   winId : windowId          //Unique id for every window you open to identify
});
```

Using this you have references to all the window all the time. When you want to close a window, just follow the LIFO process and close all the windows.

> **Note:** If you close any window and if it has exitOnClose set to true, then the entire application will close and not relaunch. So for this case, you can create an empty window as the first window to be inserted in the stack. When restarting, close all the windows except this special window whose exitOnClose is true and for all the other windows its false. So when you want to close the entire app, close all the windows. When starting, just close all except this special window.

Also any app initialization code you have, you can move it to a utility JS which will be called by the first functional window you launch.

If you still need any further input, I can post few more sample code based on that you require.

Comment: Yes, something like that. But the app is not written in Alloy. I would like to relaunch the app :)

Comment: Then the above approach which I mentioned should work as per your requirement. Once you launch from app.js create a global array and store every window reference you open. This array will work as a window stack with the top most window on the end of the array. Now you can use this array as LIFO. I have included the sample code above.